# java android: how to bring up the "in-call" dial pad?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in java-android programming.
I would like to know if there is a way to bring up the "in-call" dial pad and put a number to its dial field. With the "in-call" dial pad i mean the dial pad we use during a phone call (e.x. to type air time renewal cards code). Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you want to bring up the phone app so they can dial a prepopulated number?  Or are you looking for a numeric keypad for a textview?  Either of those can be done.  If you mean pop up the phone keyboard while they're in the middle of a call-  not really.

Comment: i want to bring up the dial pad in a midle of a call (e.x. to select from a choice menu that call provides). The same thing that we do manually for example when our cell phone runs out of credit and we need to do airtime renewal.